# SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' Doesn't stop Insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, signals

I am having problems implementing a trigger into my table. I am using MySQL, Phpmyadmin

Scenario: Table User(user_id, name, surname, date_of_joining), record(record_id, date_of_record, weight, height, id_user)

a user can have multiple records which show his weight and height at a certain date. id_user is a foreign key referencing to user_id.

I am trying to implement a trigger for insert and update which checks if date_of_record is greater than date_of_joining, if not, the insert should be stopped.

This is a trigger I tried and the insert still goes through

```
CREATE TRIGGER date_check_insert BEFORE INSERT ON record

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    DECLARE date_of_registering DATE;

    SET date_of_registering = (SELECT date_of_registering FROM user WHERE user_id = new.id_user);

    IF (new.date_of_record NOT BETWEEN date_of_registering AND CURDATE()) THEN

        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Can not insert that value";

    END IF;

END
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check SQL_Mode.

Comment: Both the SQL_Mode and the Global.SQL_Mode are: NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION, this doesn't seem to be a problem though?

Every table is running InnoDB

Comment: I just tried exchanging the if condition for new.weight = 40 and the trigger works as intended. I reckon the if condition is then not working properly but I can't understand why

Comment: Please create modelling fiddle with the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd slightly change the trigger:

- Use session variable (so no DECLARE needed)
- Put comparison logic in a single place in the WHERE clause (easier to read & understand)
- Shows reason in error message
- Use [SELECT INTO variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) instead of `SET variable = query` (not necessary, I just prefer this way)

So:

```
CREATE TRIGGER date_check_insert BEFORE INSERT ON record
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @found = NULL;

    SELECT
        user_id INTO @found
    FROM
        user
    WHERE
            user_id = NEW.id_user
        AND NEW.date_of_record BETWEEN date_of_registering AND NOW() -- or CURDATE() depend on your datetype
    ;

    IF @found IS NULL THEN
        SET @msg = CONCAT('Can not insert. Out of range value ', NEW.date_of_record);
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
    END IF;
END
```